# URI template of the newly created target must not be null

Tags: java, http, jersey

I am facing the following exception when the below piece of code is executed.. I am using Jersey client to make the call.

```
public class EventListenerClient {

    private static final String path = "/event/publish";

    private final String pluginEndpoint;

    private final Client client;

    public EventListenerClient(final Client client) {
        pluginEndpoint = AppConfig.findString(EVENT_LISTENER_ENDPOINT);
        this.client = client;
    }

//Other public methods

private Response callEventListener(final IonStruct requestStruct, final String path) {
        final Response response;
        try {
            response = client.target(pluginEndpoint).path(path).request(IonMediaType.TEXT_X_ABC_ION_TYPE)
                    .post(Entity.entity(requestStruct.toString(IonTextWriterBuilder.standard()),
                            IonMediaType.TEXT_X_ABC_ION_TYPE));
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new EventListenerException("Could not call EventListener.", e);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Its failing at this line.

```
response = client.target(pluginEndpoint).path(path).request(IonMediaType.TEXT_X_ABC_ION_TYPE)
                    .post(Entity.entity(requestStruct.toString(IonTextWriterBuilder.standard()),
                            IonMediaType.TEXT_X_ABC_ION_TYPE));
```

Has anyone faced this issue?  what is the solution here?

```
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: URI template of the newly created target must not be null.
     [java]     at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:226)
     [java]     at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:210)
     [java]     at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:72)
     [java]     at com.amazon.eventlistenerjavaclient.client.EventListenerClient.callEventListener(EventListenerClient.java:57)
     [java]     ... 5 more
```

Comment: Is your `pluginEndpoint` null?

Comment: Did you find any solution? If yes, please tell